# Highpass Lowpass filter signal, remove edge artifacts Matlab

Tags: matlab, artifact, lowpass-filter, highpass-filter

I need to filter some signals eliminating frequencies below 0.7 HZ and above 4 HZ (as suggested in the reference literature.

I'm trying this on one of the signals (second subplot): [image: My signal]

I am adding a link with the example signal used here [exampleSignal](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ft2wCe6XYsNlENvPNhQ_OqmEPOpyA4Ax/view?usp=sharing)

My signal is "ydata". To highpass the signal I tried:

```
vidInfo.frameRate = 29.9293;
highPassedSig = highpass(ydata,4,vidInfo.frameRate) % vidInfo.frameRate
```

[image: highPassedSignal]

It seems to me that there is some serious edge artifact.
If I eliminate the first 50 and the last 50 samples, this is the central part of the signal:
[image: Trimmed filtered signal]

To get rid of the edge artifact, I tried to make the signal longer at the beginning and the end. I tried two approaches: 1) zero padding, 2) doubling the first and last 50 samples of the signal. The zero padding didn't work. I found some code on mathworks for the second approach:

```
R=0.1; % 10% of signal
Nr=50;
N=size(ydata,1);
NR=min(round(N*R),Nr); % At most 50 points
for i=1:size(ydata,2)
    ydata1(:,i)=2*ydata(1,i)-flipud(ydata(2:NR+1,i));  % maintain continuity in level and slope
    ydata2(:,i)=2*ydata(end,i)-flipud(ydata(end-NR:end-1,i));
end
sigToHighPass=[ydata1;ydata;ydata2];
% Do filtering
highPassedSig = highpass(sigToHighPass,4,vidInfo.frameRate);
highPassedSig = highPassedSig(NR+1:end-NR,:)
```

This is the result:
[image: The second subplot is the filtered signal]

It looks like the edge artifact is removed. At this point, I tried to apply the low-pass filter to the highpass filtered data.

```
   N=size(highPassedSig,1);
NR=min(round(N*R),Nr); % At most 50 points
for i=1:size(highPassedSig,2)
    highPassedSig1(:,i)=2*highPassedSig(1,i)-flipud(highPassedSig(2:NR+1,i));  % maintain continuity in level and slope
    highPassedSig2(:,i)=2*highPassedSig(end,i)-flipud(highPassedSig(end-NR:end-1,i));
end
sigToLowPass=[highPassedSig1;highPassedSig;highPassedSig2];
% Do filtering
lowPassedSig = lowpass(sigToLowPass,0.7,vidInfo.frameRate);
lowPassedSig=lowPassedSig(NR+1:end-NR,:)
```

This is the result
[image: Low passed signal]
Once again, it looks like there is some serious edge artifact.

I also tried other approaches. For instance:

```
d = designfilt('lowpassfir', 'FilterOrder', 5, 'CutoffFrequency', 0.7, 'SampleRate', vidInfo.frameRate);
lowPassedSig = filter(d, ydata);
```

This is the result (subplot3):

[image: LowPassed signal with designfilt]

Does anyone have any idea how can I deal with this?

Thank you,
Gianluca

Comment: You may have better luck answering your question in a more specific Stack Exchange channel: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the fundamental problem I see in your approach is that you are miss-interpreting your cut-off frequencies. If you want to remove frequencies below 0.7 Hz and above 4 Hz, you need :

- A lowpass filter with a cut-off frequency at 4 Hz.
- A highpass filter with a cut-off frequency at 0.7 Hz.

Not the other way around !
This is easily done using the `highpass` and `lowpass` functions as you suggested. They are dealing with the padding automatically. If you want you can design your own digital filter BUT with the cut-off frequencies mentionned above :)

A matlab code that does what you want is :

```
ydata = load("signaldata.mat","-mat");
ydata = ydata.ydata;

f = 29.9293;

lp = 0.7;
hp = 4;

[y_hp,d_hp] = highpass(ydata,lp,f);
[y_lphp,d_lp] = lowpass(y_hp,hp,f);

%% plot result
x = (1:length(ydata))/f;
figure;
subplot(3,1,1);
plot(x,ydata);
legend("Original");
subplot(3,1,2);
plot(x,y_hp);
legend("Highpass");
subplot(3,1,3);
plot(x,y_lphp);
xlabel('Time [s]');
legend("Lowpass");

%% plot filters
figure;
[h,w] = freqz(d_hp);
subplot(2,2,1);
title('Highpass');
loglog(w/pi*f/2,abs(h));
subplot(2,2,3);
semilogx(w/pi*f/2,angle(h)/pi*180);
[h,w] = freqz(d_lp);
subplot(2,2,2);
title('Lowpass');
loglog(w/pi*f/2,abs(h));
subplot(2,2,4);
semilogx(w/pi*f/2,angle(h)/pi*180);
```

This gives the following plots :
The input and output data
[image: Input and Output data]
The frequency responses (magnitude and phase) of the filters.
[image: Highpass and lowpass filters designed by Matlab]

I hope this explanation will help you !

Comment: OMG, such a rookie mistake. Thank you very much, worked perfectly :)
The only thing is: I don't understand how to interpret the second plot (the freq responses). Can you point me to some easy material online to learn interpreting these?

Comment: These plots are called _bode plots_, the English Wikipedia page on this topic is quite well explained but rather math involved (stick to the figures). If you want a little crash course about it, I definitely recommend the YouTube Channel of Brian Douglas, it has a playlist on [bode plot basics](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_eh1conN6YM&list=PLUMWjy5jgHK24TCFwngV5MeiruHxt1BQR).